# Pulling images from Instagram Gem over secure domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

I am using the Instagram gem to pull information from the API, but I am getting an error in my browser console because the images are coming through as HTTP on an HTTPS site.

#### View

```
<% instagram.each do |i| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to i.link, :target => "_blank" do %>
          <%= image_tag i.images.standard_resolution.url %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

#### Application Controller

```
def instagram Instagram.user_recent_media("xxxxxx", {:count => 6})
    rescue nil 
end
```

#### Initializer

```
require "instagram"

Instagram.configure do |config|
    config.client_id = "xxx"
    config.access_token = "xxx"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram will serve assets over http and https, so just adjust your URL. You can make the URL protocol relative, so that the image is always loaded in the browser using the correct protocol. Try this in your view:

```
<%= image_tag i.images.standard_resolution.url.sub(/^https?\:/, '') %>
```